# update element , with selection choices

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am creating a form, with colorwheel, and text colour selection.

Essentially, we have a logo that will load dynamically in the element ( div ) container.

The colorwheel, will create the bg colour
The radio buttons allow to select text colour.

Any js gurus, know how to create the js to create the div, that changes bg colour and text colour of the preview div as per the image.
[image]

Very basic example ( image paths changed ) but works. http://www.jsfiddle.net/QZuA5/
Essentially its the preview div, I want to create. We can place logo dynamically using absolute positioning.

So essentially its the js to create the div placeholder bg colour and font text colour, that will parse valuse when we submit the form.

Cheers

Comment: can you explain more detailed on what part exactly you need?

Comment: See the Preview with the Div underneath, that bg colour needs to change, when we use colour wheel. When user selects text colour: black or white radio buttons, the text in that div "Text Colour Selected: White" changes colour and if they choose black, it turns black and displays: Text Colour selected: Black" cheers

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the line: *create the div, that changes bg colour and text colour of the preview div as per the image. *

In raw Javascript, you can dynamically create a div like this:

```
var div = document.createElement("DIV");
```

You can access the styles of `div` with its `.style` property to change everything else you need, whenever you want:

```
div.backgroundColor = "#123456";
div.style.color = "green";

div.style.height = "100px";
```

Then you can append `div` anywhere you want with the `.appendChild` method:

```
document.appendChild(div);
```

or

```
document.getElementById('anotherElement').appendChild(div);
```